# Nginx rewrite capture comma separated strings

Tags: regex, nginx

I have some a url rewrite that I need that will capture

```
598ccb3055027300394ad711,598cf4f955027300386f3232
```

in a url

Like

```
/598ccb3055027300394ad711,598cf4f955027300386f3232?other=param
```

How would I capture this? I have tried ([a-zA-Z0-9,]+) but it only captures the first alphanumeric string.

Comment: Your regex does match `**  Grp 0 -  ( pos 1 , len 49 ) 
598ccb3055027300394ad711,598cf4f955027300386f3232  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 1 , len 49 ) 
598ccb3055027300394ad711,598cf4f955027300386f3232`  Do you need it to match the entire string as well ?

Comment: When I try this regex in nginx it only captures the first alphanumeric string before the comma

Comment: That's strange, there is nothing in  `[a-zA-Z0-9,]+` that would make it stop at a comma, unless the comma `,` has special meaning inside a class, or it is _not_ a comma at all, but another Unicode look alike. Or, the comma in the url is not actually a comma. Try `[a-zA-Z0-9,]+.[a-zA-Z0-9,]+` as a test.

Comment: @MikeL how you capture it in nginx? Your regex is correct.

Comment: @maxim.u I have a rewrites.conf that is loaded that has all our rewrites. From there, I have a line that says `rewrite "^/services/templates/([^?]+)" /services/service.php?service=templates&templates=$1&$3 last;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would give this a shot:

```
/([^?]+)
```

a python example:

```
import re
text = "/598ccb3055027300394ad711,598cf4f955027300386f3232?other=param"
match = re.search("/([^?]+)", text)
if match:
    print (match.group(1))
```

should output:

```
598ccb3055027300394ad711,598cf4f955027300386f3232
```

You want to capture from that / up to the first non ?, and that is what you'll get

Comment: Is `(^?)` a valid nginx regex construct?

Comment: whoops, sorry. type-o. updated.  I forgot the [  and ] for the character class

Comment: I accepted this as the correct answer, however it was not working due to a rewrite that I had before the rewrite I wanted to achieve first

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+,[a-zA-Z0-9]+).+
```

And then capture the first and only group.  The group excludes the starting forward slash and anything including and after a non-alphanumeric character is reached after the parsed group (and so it only *does* capture the part you're interested in).

Comment: Not sure what I am doing wrong here, but it only seems to capture the first one